# Cannot download txt file using keras.utils.get_file

Tags: python-3.x, keras, char, project, recurrent-neural-network

I cannot download a .txt file using Kera's get_file() function my code

```
shakespeare_url = "https://homl.info/shakespeare" # shortcut URL
filepath = keras.utils.get_file("shakespeare.txt", shakespeare_url)
with open(filepath) as f:
    shakespeare_text = f.read()
```

I get an error message 
NameError: name 'Keras' is not defined 
I've re-installed Keras to no avail

Comment: Keras and keras are not the same thing in python, as it is a case sensitive language. What is the full traceback of this error?

Comment: here is the traceback information: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-738e084e59e2> in <module>
      1 shakespeare_url = "https://homl.info/shakespeare" # shortcut URL
----> 2 filepath = keras.utils.get_file("shakespeare.txt", shakespeare_url)
      3 with open(filepath) as f:
      4     shakespeare_text = f.read()

NameError: name 'keras' is not defined

Comment: Did you import keras?

Comment: I inputed import keras and Jupyter commented Using TensorFlow backend.

Comment: Yes, that is normal, you can only use libraries after importing them

Comment: I just ran the code again and it's downloading the txt file. thanks for your help!